# Java JScience: How to print the whole Real number?

Tags: java, jscience

I wrote some testing code which calculated Pi to whatever thing I wanted it to calculate to. It looks something like this:

```
public static void piCalculatorMethod1() {
    int iteration = 1000000;

    Real pi = Real.valueOf(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < iteration + 1; i++) {
        Real current = pi;
        Real addendum = Real.valueOf((1/Math.pow(i, 2)));

        pi = current.plus(addendum);
    }

    pi = pi.times(6);

    pi = pi.sqrt();

    System.out.println(pi.toString());
}
```

Quite unfortunately, the output decides it would look like this:

```
3.14159169866
```

I'm quite sure the end value is much more accurate than that, because I've seen what values they are actually adding, and that's much more accurate than that.

How do I get `System.out.println` to show me the whole Real instead of just the first few digits?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to question your assumption about the convergence of the series. This approximation of π relies on Euler's solution to the [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). Empirically, the example below finds the deviation from π<sup>2</sup>/6 for a number of iteration counts. As you can see, each order of magnitude in the iteration count adds no more than one decimal digit of accuracy.

Code:

```
Real PI_SQUARED_OVER_6 = Real.valueOf(Math.pow(Math.PI, 2) / 6);
for (int p = 0; p < 7; p++) {
    int iterations = (int) Math.pow(10, p);
    Real pi = Real.valueOf(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < iterations + 1; i++) {
        pi = pi.plus(Real.valueOf(1 / Math.pow(i, 2)));
    }
    System.out.println("10^" + p + ": " + PI_SQUARED_OVER_6.minus(pi));
}
```

Console:

```
10^0: 6.44934066848226E-1
10^1: 9.5166335681686E-2
10^2: 9.950166663334E-3
10^3: 9.99500166667E-4
10^4: 9.9995000167E-5
10^5: 9.999950000E-6
10^6: 9.99999500E-7
```