# How to get greater precision for PI using the Harmonic Series

Tags: java, pi

trying to get back into Java and have decided to tackle PI. So I made this program based on the Harmonic Series:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{   
    double denominator = 1.0;
    double tempValue;
    double PI = 0.0;

    // End point for program
    double stopPoint = 1234.5;

    for( int i = 1; i < stopPoint; i++  )
    {
        tempValue = Math.sqrt( (1/(denominator*denominator))/6 );

        PI = PI + tempValue;
        denominator = denominator + 1.0;
    }
    System.out.println( "PI = " + PI );
```

The application prints this:

```
PI = 3.1417306496998294
```

So you can see its mildly working. But when I change the stopPoint value any more I'm not getting a change in precision, at all.

For example changing it to `1234.75` gives the same answer - or perhaps `print` can't display the exact value? If so what is the best way to print out values like these?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've added this code as its a change to the code posted above. Some of the changes include the use of `Big Decimal` and the inclusion of a `while loop` instead of a `for`.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;

public class MyPI 
{
final static BigDecimal ONE = new BigDecimal(1);
final static BigDecimal SIX = new BigDecimal(6);

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    BigDecimal deno, temp, tempPI;

    int start, end;
    start = 1;
    end = 500000;
    temp = new BigDecimal(0);

    // Starting denominator point
    deno = ONE;

    while( start < end )
    {
        // Without precision and rounding mode, it will try to return a
        // never ending number
        temp = temp.add( ONE.divide(deno.pow(2),MathContext.DECIMAL64) );
        deno = deno.add(ONE);

        start = start + 1;
    }
    tempPI = temp.multiply(SIX);

    // Need to convert to double for square root
    double PI = Math.sqrt( tempPI.doubleValue() );
    System.out.println( "PI: " + PI );
}
}
```

This produces the following result:

```
PI: 3.1415907437318054
```

Thanks all for the help - will probably add a timer to track how long it takes to do this.

Comment: The harmonic series converges *very* ***slowly*** to PI.

Comment: Why not having a long stop point?

Comment: _Very_ slowly, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17084000/230513).

Comment: Yes i know its not as quick as many other formulas but his is just for starting off - I don't want to jump into the big ones yet - having done enough research into first understanding them

Comment: I;ve been using the BigDecimal type instead of the double but have hit abit of a roadblock - the square root. This is for double values which would mean I've have to change the value hitherto to a double - losing the precision that I wanted in the first place. So how do I move forward from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I've been using the `BigDecimal` type instead of the `double`, but I have hit a bit of a roadblock—the square root.*

Don't take the square root of each term. As shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17084000/230513), add the terms of the [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), which has the exact sum π<sup>2</sup>/6. When your loop terminates, multiply by six and *then* take a single square root.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more precision, you can use Java's [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use Java BigDecimal instead of Double that has a limited precision.

Answer (score 1):

The [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class can give you "arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers", which is what you want in this case, although the instances of BigDecimal are a little more tricky to work with than literals, the class actually works quickly and can be used to do what you need fairly accurately.

Just for your information, though, using the harmonic series to calculate Pi is pretty inefficient, but I understand doing it as a fun program or to learn something new.